# How to turn off page numbering for just a page?

Tags: page-numbering

I know that `\pagenumbering{gobble}` makes the page numbering off. But when I use, for example `\pagenumbering{arabic}` again, page numbering starts over from 1. How to make it start from an offset?

Comment: `\setcounter{page}{100}` is what you want?

Comment: Partha D's answer is the answer to the question in the title, but the text of your question appears to be asking a different question about changing the value of the counter rather than affecting a single page. Perhaps you could edit the question to clarify the actual problem?

Answer (score 8):

You have to look at what `\pagenumbering` actually does in order to understand why (from the [LaTeX kernel](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co)):

```
\def\pagenumbering#1{%
  \global\c@page \@ne % <---------------------------- 1
  \gdef\thepage{\csname @#1\endcsname \c@page}}% <--- 2
```

Note how `\pagenumbering{<scheme>}` does *two* things:

1. Globally (re)sets the page number counter `\c@page` to 1;
2. Globally (re)defines `\thepage` to be a representation of the page counter according to `<type>`. Here `<scheme>` is defined as a macro `\@<scheme>`. So, `\pagenumbering{gobble}` results in `\@gobble`.

Now that you know it (re)sets the page number back to 1, you have a couple of options:

1. Store the page number *before* setting it to `gobble`, and use that when you restore the numbering scheme.

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[paper=a5paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
   \usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

   \newcounter{savepage}

   \begin{document}

   \sloppy% Just for this example
   \lipsum[1-20]

   \setcounter{savepage}{\value{page}}% Store page number on page 6
   \pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page number
   \lipsum[1-2]

   \pagenumbering{arabic}% Restore page numbering
   \setcounter{page}{\numexpr\value{savepage}+2}% Restore original numbering + offset (should be page 8)
   \lipsum[3-20]

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Just set the page number outright using `\setcounter{page}{<number>}` after restoring the numbering scheme (using `\pagenumbering{arabic}`, say). A similar technique is used as in (1) above.
3. Use a page style to change the appearance of the page number (or remove it), leaving the counter untouched.

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[paper=a5paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
   \usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

   \fancypagestyle{strangepage}{%
     \fancyhf{}% Remove header/footer
     \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
     \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule (default)
     \fancyhead[C]{non-default header}% Header
     \fancyfoot[C]{no page number}% Footer
   }

   % Set default fancy header
   \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
   \fancyhead[C]{default header}% Header
   \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% Footer
   \pagestyle{fancy}% Set page style

   \begin{document}

   \sloppy% Just for this example
   \lipsum[1-20]

   \thispagestyle{strangepage}% Change page style *just* for this page
   \lipsum[1-20]

   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: There is a problem with your approach. It manipulated the page style and everything got bigger and so weird.

Comment: @lonesome: If you don't like the `\thispagestyle` approach, I did provide other options. Alternatively, can you provide details of what your concern is through a minimal example that replicates the problem?

Comment: Well, What I want is to only remove numbering for a page and continue with the same numbering from next page. I used your first example and fonts got much bigger and not just for that page, but for every page.

Comment: @lonesome: It doesn't happen with my example, so I don't know what you might be doing differently.

Answer (score 4):

What about `\thispagestyle{empty}` ?

That should print no page number (supposed to be 73, say) on the page where this command is placed, and continue numbering next page (74) as usual.